# Override a variable on keyPressed()

Tags: processing

I am trying to change the column header from a table using a variable name that changes using keyPressed() but it is not working.

```
String colSub;
Table dataTable;

void setup()
{
  for(int k =0; k<dataTable.length; k++)
   {
     float xrate = dataTable.getFloat(k, colSub);
   }
}

void draw()
{
  rect(400,300,150,150);
}

void keyPressed()
{
  if (key == '1')
 {
   colSub = "AVERAGE_ENGLISH";
 }
 if (key == '2')
 {
   colSub = "AVERAGE_MATHS";
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did. It's in Processing

Comment: Sorry my bad! Didn't know that language

Comment: When do you render the table?

Answer (score 0):

setup() only gets called once, at the beginning of your Processing program. In order to achieve whatever goal you may have, you should copy your code to the keyPressed() section, so everytime the key gets pressed the values get updated. Again your code doesn't do anything with xrate, but you would require to make your variable xrate global, so that setup() and keyPressed() can access this data.